# Convert Windows Java Commands to Linux Java Commands?

Tags: java, windows, linux, command

I have the following text in a BAT files so I java program in windows. I was wondering how you can do this in linux.

File 1:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javac.exe" -sourcepath src -classpath bin;deps\jml-1.0b3-full.jar;deps\mail.jar -d bin src/*.java
```

File 2:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\java.exe" -Xmx1536m -classpath bin;deps\jml-1.0b3-full.jar;deps\mail.jar HelloWorld
```

Id really appreciate it if someone would convert those to linux commands.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options to `java` and `javac` are the same on all platforms. The only things that will change are the file path, for eg. `deps\mail.jar` might become `deps/mail.jar`; and the classpath separator, `:` (colon) instead of `;` (semicolon).

Answer (score 2):

- get rid of the quotations - spaces in linux are not a usual practice, so the quotes are not needed
- change `;` to `:` as classpath separator
- change slashes to `/`
- make the file `.sh`

that should be it.

Comment: Folder names on OS X *can* have spaces.

Comment: They can in Linux as well -- they just need to be escaped properly. :)

Comment: @casablanca - ... and the person who puts them there needs to be sent for counselling :-)

Comment: @casablanca: yes, by putting the path in quotes for instance, which makes the advice given by this answer wrong.

Comment: @JeremyP - not quite. I rephrased the answer so that it is clear that on Linux it is not customary to use spaces. And by default java is installed on a no-space directory. (on distros I've used at least)

Answer (score 0):

check if java SDK (java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel or Sun) exists and in the PATH

```
which javac
```

Next put the same options
 javac -sourcepath ..